# Preventing a swf from invoking ExternalInterface calls without recompiling it

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm working with a third party swf that I cannot change and am charged with making it work in a local environment, loaded within a container application I have built. The SWF was published for accessing the network sandbox, so whenever it invokes the ExternalInterface in a local html container, it throws a security sandbox error and kills execution. The ExternalInterface calls are all non-critical (logging) so if I can block them somehow, then I won't have a problem any more.

I'm pretty certain this is not possible, but I'm hoping that someone here can prove otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible (or at least it's not trivial). I once did something similar (just removing a couple of calls) in an AS 2.0 project, using [FLASM](http://www.nowrap.de/flasm.html), an actionscript assembler/disassembler. But this tool only works for AS 2.0 and I'm not aware of other similar tool for AS 3.0 (though some might exist).

However, perhaps you could set up a local web server, which is simple enough (WAMP, XAMP, etc on windows) and run your html as `http://localhost/myApp/index.html`, instead of running it directly from the file system. That could be an easy workaround under the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something but external interface is used primarily to call javascript in the SWF's parent.

The security error being thrown should indicate what it was trying to call. All you have to do in the HTML that wraps up the SWF is provide the methods the SWF is attempting to call.

So the SWF might have `ExternalInterface.call("js_function");` and so in your wrapper have

```
<script>
function js_function() { // do nothing }
</script>
```

Comment: Security sandbox restrictions prevent the inner swf from calling javascript at all, regardless of whether the functions exist, because the inner swf is compiled for network access instead of local file system access.

Comment: Ok, well you could use Macromedia Flash Local Content Updater which allows you to change a SWF's security settings of a SWF Quote Adobe: 'This tool allows you to change the security sandbox that the SWF file operates in when it is played as a local file in Flash Player 8 and above.' Download here http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html towards bottom

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about this tool, although it hasn't solved my problem. This seems to be intractable; Adobe has tightened the security sandbox too much around local content, so I'll have to pursue another option.

Answer (score 0):

Hacky as hell, but you could in your parent application edit the .prototype of the ExternalInterface class to replace "call" with a function of your own choosing. I haven't tested this, it's only a theory, but it would look something like this:

```
    // in your main application's wrapper, before you load in the .swf you're working with

    ExternalInterface.prototype.call = function(value:String):void { 
trace("You just tried to call a js function called '" + value + "', but I intercepted it."); 
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot, but Adobe robbed the prototype of most of its power in AS3. I'll let you know if it worked.

Comment: No dice. Can't redefine functions in AS3 via the prototype chain, unfortunately.